# RestController fill automatically request body and headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

We have RestController endpoints which receive parameters in body, and also from headers

So we create RequestVO object which is automatically filled with JSON(/XML) parameters

```
@PostMapping
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> endpoint(@RequestBody RequestVO requestVO, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
```

But for request/header's parameters we must use setters to fill the values

Is there a way to automatically fill object with headers/request parameters?

Comment: Seems like this would be confusing to the user of the API, where `RequestVO` defines attributes that cannot actually be used in the payload.  Consider creating a `DomainRequestVO`, which is composed of the `RequestVO` and the header values.

Comment: @AndrewS but how do I fill it automatically with headers as well as body?

Comment: I would keep them separate, where `RequestVO` contains the attributes expected in the body, and the headers through @RequestHeader (Michal Drozd's answer).  Then in the `endpoint` method, use a  builder to compose a domain object that combines `RequestVO` and the headers.  And the domain object is passed to the service layer.

Comment: Another option might be to use a filter or interceptor to combine the body and headers before reaching the endpoint.  But that might complicate other processes, such as generating OpenAPI documentation.

Comment: @AndrewS you have good points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you can use something like this

```
@RequestHeader(value="Key") String value,
@RequestHeader(value="Content-Type") String contentType,
```

...

Comment: ok, but I want an object (RequestVO) to be filled with all those values

Comment: then I believe you need implement your own converter (check ConverterFactory etc), there is way how you can convert incoming request to object you want.

Comment: afaik i believe that would be breaking change to fill request body with headers